# How Do I Change the Text of a TextMeshPro Object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a TextMeshPro object update to show the value of a sensitivity slider in my game. However, it doesn't update!

I've tried looking it up but almost every tutorial I've followed hasn't helped.

Here is the 'PlayerScript' script, which gets the value on the slider (this functions):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Update is called once per frame
    public float moveSpeed = 600f;
    public static float publicSensitivity;

    float movement = 0f;
    void Update()
    {
        movement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    }

    public void SetSensitivity(float sensitivity)
    {
        Debug.Log(sensitivity);
        moveSpeed = sensitivity * 12;
        publicSensitivity = sensitivity;

    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.forward, movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime * -moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

and here is the 'ChangePercentage' script, which is meant to change the TextMeshPro text object to reflect the value on the slider (not changing. By default, the object reads "foo". When I open the options menu, it changed to read 0%, but only once. This means that it must update but not continuously):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ChangePercentage : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TextMeshProUGUI self;
    void Update()
    {
        self.text = (PlayerScript.publicSensitivity).ToString() + "%";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I safely assume that the slider's `On Value Changed` event has been set with `SetSensitivity` function in the inspector?

Comment: Yep. The sensitivity of the game changes when I move the slider, so I'm not sure what's wrong with this.

Comment: `Debug.Log('sensitivity')` logs the correct value? Can you also log `publicSensitivity` after assigning it? If its value also doesn't change i would point to the `static` keyword as the error. A cleaner alternative would be making the `PlayerScript` a [Singleton](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) or using the instance of the class.

Comment: In general you should rather make that event driven and not poll it in an `Update` method every frame. Instead set text only when the value is actually changed! Is it maybe possible that the component gets disabled for some reason?

Comment: You could e.g. register a callback to the [`slider.onValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-onValueChanged.html) or simply call a custom `public static event Action<float> OnSensitivityChanged;`

Comment: In general do you try to set breakpoints and [debug](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/debugging-unity-games-visual-studio) your code?

Comment: Oh. Works now. Not sure what I changed, but thanks everyone!

Comment: Hey, @mreyeball - if you're designing a settings page maybe use OnGUI() instead of Update(). https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html

Answer (score 1):

How/where is the SetSensitivity method called?
I would recommend to use the slider object and then set the sensitivity to slider.value .
Example:

```
unsing UnityEngine.UI; 
public slider sensitivity_slider;
public static float sensitivity;

public void Update(){
sensitivity = sensitivity_slider.value;
}
```

You can alsow make a script that displays the slidervalue directly.

Hope i could help, sorry for my bad english.